# Encoding lost when camunda variable injected in a freemarker template placeholder

Tags: freemarker, camunda

In one of a camunda bpmn I have a service task defined like this:

```
<bpmn:serviceTask id="ps2FreigebenEmail" name="E-Mail an Versicherer:" camunda:asyncBefore="true">
  <bpmn:extensionElements>
    <camunda:connector>
      <camunda:inputOutput>
        <camunda:inputParameter name="to">${mailRecipient}</camunda:inputParameter>
        <camunda:inputParameter name="html">
          <camunda:script scriptFormat="freemarker" resource="${&#34;classpath://email/statistik2_freigeben_email_&#34;.concat(&#34;de&#34;).concat(&#34;.ftl&#34;)}" />
        </camunda:inputParameter>
        <camunda:inputParameter name="subject">Statistik 2 prüfbereit</camunda:inputParameter>
      </camunda:inputOutput>
      <camunda:connectorId>mail-send</camunda:connectorId>
    </camunda:connector>
    <camunda:inputOutput>
      <camunda:inputParameter name="url">${urlResolver.getFrontendUrl()}</camunda:inputParameter>
    </camunda:inputOutput>
  </bpmn:extensionElements>
  <bpmn:incoming>...</bpmn:incoming>
  <bpmn:outgoing>...</bpmn:outgoing>
</bpmn:serviceTask>
```

Freemarker template looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Guten Tag</p>
    <p>
      Die Statistik 2 der Versicherungsgesellschaft ${gesellschaft.gesellschaftsnummer?c}
  ${gesellschaft.bezeichnung} wurde erstellt.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Variable "gesellschaft" is serialized like this:

```
Gesellschaft gesellschaft = .. some POJO
ObjectValue gesellschaftValue =           
Variables.objectValue(gesellschaft)
.serializationDataFormat("application/json").create();
delegateExecution.setVariable("gesellschaft", gesellschaftValue);"
```

Then serialized value is saved in table act_ge_bytearray and looks like this:

```
{"gesellschaftsnummer":20060,"bezeichnung":"Zürich","dabTennantId": "41c6dbea-d160-48ae-9000-6d5db4b55d14"}
```

When the email is sent, then the encoding of "bezeichnung"-Field is lost:

```
Guten Tag
Die Statistik 2 der Versicherungsgesellschaft 20060 Z�rich wurde erstellt.
```

- I have tried to set:
- ftl encoding to UTF-8
- email encoding to UTF-8
- VM file.encoding to UTF-8

Comment: When you have "ü" directly in your template (as simple static text), does that works? If so, then the problem likely happens when reading the JSON. But the last itself can also be proven if it works if you edit the JSON to replace `Zürich` with `Z\u00FCrich`.

Comment: I added some special characters in the template: **<p>Guten Tag ä ö ü</p>**. Even if I mark the template with <#ftl encoding="utf-8">, the special characters are not displayed properly: **Guten Tag � � �**.

Comment: But the email part containing the wrong encoded characters is of type: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: What do you get if you put this into the template: `${'C\x00FCrich'}`. If that will be distorted as well, then the problem is not (or not only) the encoding of the template. So then, it could be the part of the system that encodes the output of the template. (That's not in the hands of FreeMarker, as it prints into a `Writer`.)